Problema con grid y overflow CSS
Estoy implementando una página con HTML y CSS. Para su estructura estoy utilizando grid.
El problema surge porque el texto de la etiqueta <main></main> es extenso y, según las dimensiones del navegador, no se muestra correctamente aunque utilice la propiedad overflow-y: auto;
He visto que reduciendo el tamaño del texto o ampliando el área que ocupa <main></main> el texto se muestra completamente, pero no es la solución que tengo que usar.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar íntegramente el texto sin modificar el tamaño de la fuente o de las áreas del grid?


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
}
div.container > * {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
div.container > header {
    background-color: red;
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
div.container > aside:first-of-type {
    background-color: yellow;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
div.container > main {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
div.container > aside:last-of-type {
    background-color: green;
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
div.container > footer {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
}
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>Header</header>
        <aside>Right</aside>
        <main>En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor. Una olla de algo más vaca que carnero, salpicón las más noches, duelos y quebrantos los sábados, lentejas los viernes, algún palomino de añadidura los domingos, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda. El resto della concluían sayo de velarte, calzas de velludo para las fiestas con sus pantuflos de lo mismo, los días de entre semana se honraba con su vellori de lo más fino. Tenía en su casa una ama que pasaba de los cuarenta, y una sobrina que no llegaba a los veinte, y un mozo de campo y plaza, que así ensillaba el rocín como tomaba la podadera. Frisaba la edad de nuestro hidalgo con los cincuenta años, era de complexión recia, seco de carnes, enjuto de rostro; gran madrugador y amigo de la caza. Quieren decir que tenía el sobrenombre de Quijada o Quesada (que en esto hay alguna diferencia en los autores que deste caso escriben), aunque por conjeturas verosímiles se deja entender que se llama Quijana; pero esto importa poco a nuestro cuento; basta que en la narración dél no se salga un punto de la verdad.</main>
        <aside>Left</aside>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>




A ver, a que te refieres con mostrar el texto de manera integra, sin modificar su tamaño ??? Si la ventana es pequeña, no podrías mostrar más que una letra.

puedes hacer algunos ajustes en tu CSS. En particular, puedes asegurarte de que el contenedor  tenga un alto definido y que el contenido dentro de él se despliegue correctamente con barras de desplazamiento cuando sea necesario


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
}

div.container>* {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.container>header {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

div.container>aside:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

div.container>main {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  /* Añade un poco de espacio interno */
}

div.container>aside:last-of-type {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

div.container>footer {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>Header</header>
    <aside>Right</aside>
    <main>En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor. Una olla de algo más vaca que carnero, salpicón las más noches, duelos
      y quebrantos los sábados, lentejas los viernes, algún palomino de añadidura los domingos, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda. El resto della concluían sayo de velarte, calzas de velludo para las fiestas con sus pantuflos de lo mismo, los días
      de entre semana se honraba con su vellori de lo más fino. Tenía en su casa una ama que pasaba de los cuarenta, y una sobrina que no llegaba a los veinte, y un mozo de campo y plaza, que así ensillaba el rocín como tomaba la podadera. Frisaba la
      edad de nuestro hidalgo con los cincuenta años, era de complexión recia, seco de carnes, enjuto de rostro; gran madrugador y amigo de la caza. Quieren decir que tenía el sobrenombre de Quijada o Quesada (que en esto hay alguna diferencia en los
      autores que deste caso escriben), aunque por conjeturas verosímiles se deja entender que se llama Quijana; pero esto importa poco a nuestro cuento; basta que en la narración dél no se salga un punto de la verdad.</main>
    <aside>Left</aside>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>



display: flex; permite que el contenido dentro de <main> se maneje como un contenedor flexible.
flex-direction: column; asegura que los elementos dentro de <main> se alineen verticalmente.
justify-content: flex-start; alinea el contenido verticalmente desde el principio del contenedor.
align-items: flex-start; alinea el contenido horizontalmente desde el principio del contenedor.
padding: 10px; en <main>:
Añade un poco de espacio interno alrededor del contenido dentro de <main>, lo que puede ayudar a que el texto no quede demasiado pegado a los bordes.

Al final era un problema de flex. Bastaba con añadir la regla CSS flex-wrap: wrap; dentro del código de la etiqueta main para que la propiedad overflow funcione correctamente.

Por mi parte aun no entiendo el problema en tu pregunta y menos como flex-wrap: wrap lo resuelve, y aun menos teniendo que el main contiene solo texto, donde el flex-wrap no aplica
